# Finding all real $a$ such that $16x^4-(a)x^3+(2a+17)x^2−(a)x+16=0$ has four distinct roots in geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

> Determine all real values of the parameter, $a$, for which the equation  $$16x^4−(a)x^3+(2a+17)x^2−(a)x+16=0$$ has exactly four distinct real roots that form a geometric progression?

I noticed that the coefficients are symmetric: namely, the first coefficient is the same as the fifth one, the second is the same as the fourth, and the third is the same as the third.

I don’t know how to proceed using Vieta's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do like derivation of Vieta's formulas rather than the formulas themselves.
Let $b,\,bq,\,bq^2,\,bq^3$ be the roots of $$p(x)=(x-b)(x-bq)(x-bq^2)(x-bq^3)$$ $$\hbox{and }f(x)=x^4−\frac{a}{16}x^3+\frac{2a+17}{16}x^2−\frac{a}{16}x+1.$$
It can be verified that [$$p(x)=b^4 q^6 - b^3 (q^3 + q^2 + q + 1) q^3 x + \\
b^2 (q^4 + q^3 + 2 q^2 + q + 1) q x^2 - b (q^3 + q^2 + q + 1) x^3 + x^4$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-b%29%28x-bq%29%28x-bq%5E2%29%28x-bq%5E3%29)
But $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ are same degree polynomials with highest degree coefficient $1$ and the same roots $\Rightarrow$ they have the same coefficients.
$$\begin{cases}
b^4 q^6=1\\
16 b^3 (q^3 + q^2 + q + 1) q^3=a\\
16 b^2 (q^4 + q^3 + 2 q^2 + q + 1) q = 2a+17\\
16 b (q^3 + q^2 + q + 1) = a
\end{cases}$$
Hence [$a=170$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b%5E4+q%5E6%3D1%2C+16+b%5E3+%28q%5E3+%2B+q%5E2+%2B+q+%2B+1%29+q%5E3%3Da%2C+16+b%5E2+%28q%5E4+%2B+q%5E3+%2B+2+q%5E2+%2B+q+%2B+1%29+q+%3D+2a%2B17%2C+16+b+%28q%5E3+%2B+q%5E2+%2B+q+%2B+1%29+%3D+a).